# Class structure confirmation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this class file call **SMSHelper.cs** First I just wanted to know is my written structure is Correct or Wrong?(My class file name is also SMSHelper.cs & my first class also SMSHelper here you can see in the code.).

Basically I have 3 classes in same file. One class has the same  name as the file name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace SMSBase.SMSFunction
{
public class SMSHelper : DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase
{
 // Some Code here 
 // Return Something here
}
 public class Validator
   {
    public bool IsValidate(string Item)
    { 
    // Some Code Here Not return anything

 }

  public class HuntingDate
     {
    //Implementation & Constructor here.. Return Something
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking? This doesn't seem to be *wrong*, but i would advise you to split your classes up into individual ones, not just dump them al in 1 file

Comment: @JaneDoe I wanted to acccess those classes from another file..(Using create object ).Then i'm having a trouble know ? Class file name & one of my class names are same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your class structure (except one missing bracket). And there is no matter your class name and file name are same. You can access and initialize your class objects like that...

```
SMSBase.SMSFunction.SMSHelper objSMSHelper = new SMSBase.SMSFunction.SMSHelper();

SMSBase.SMSFunction.Validator objValidator = new SMSBase.SMSFunction.Validator();

SMSBase.SMSFunction.HuntingDate objHuntingDate = new SMSBase.SMSFunction.HuntingDate();
```

This `SMSBase.SMSFunction` is your namespace... you can access classes by your namespace or include this namespace in the class header like

```
using SMSBase.SMSFunction
```

Comment: Instead of this Public class Can i use Public partial class ?

Comment: because i here i written several classes in same .cs file

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in opening closing brackets:

```
namespace SMSBase.SMSFunction 
{ 
public class SMSHelper : DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase 
{  // Some Code here   // Return Something here 
}  
public class Validator    
{     
public bool IsValidate(string Item)    
 {      // Some Code Here Not return anything 

 }
}   
 public class HuntingDate     
 {     //Implementation & Constructor here.. Return Something   
 }      

 }
```

If that is what you are asking.

Comment: No no.. not the brackets.I ask it about i wanted to access this class memebers from another file.Lets say i wanted to access some class member from another class in different file can i do that ?

Comment: by adding namespace at top like #using SMSBase.SMSFunction; in the file where you want to access these classes.

Comment: @Learner Of course you can do it, if those members are `public`. It doesn't matter which file the class is in as long as you use the correct namespace, as ebad86 said

Answer (score 0):

*Yes as Talha ,said one bracket is missing.Try to put that.*

When we want to call the class name its better to call with "namespace.ClassName" format which gives clarity to the compiler.